# Download dynamically generated image from ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, image-processing, dynamic

I'm dynamically generating image from text, and existing image on my asp.net website.

Here is the code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tytul = Request.QueryString["Tytul"];
    var tresc = Request.QueryString["Tresc"];

    var font = new Font("Verdana", 23);

    var brushForeColor = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    var brushBackColor = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(248, 247, 182));

    var test = new Bitmap(450, 60);
    var graphicstest = Graphics.FromImage(test);
    var width = (int)graphicstest.MeasureString(tresc, font).Width;
    var height = (int)graphicstest.MeasureString(tresc, font).Height;

    while (width > 450)
    {
        height = height + 25;
        width = width - 450;
    }

    var heightall = height + 40 + 30 + 100;

    var bitmap = new Bitmap(450, heightall);
    var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

    var displayRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(450, 40));
    graphics.FillRectangle(brushBackColor, displayRectangle);

    //Define string format 
    var format1 = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip);
    format1.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

    var format2 = new StringFormat(format1);

    //Draw text string using the text format
    graphics.DrawString(tytul, font, brushForeColor, displayRectangle, format2);

    // Rysowanie drugiego boxa

    brushBackColor = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(253, 253, 202));
    font = new Font("Verdana", 18);

    displayRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 40), new Size(450, height + 30));
    graphics.FillRectangle(brushBackColor, displayRectangle);

    displayRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 55), new Size(450, height + 15));


    graphics.DrawString(tresc, font, brushForeColor, displayRectangle, format2);

    graphics.DrawImage(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(".") + "/gfx/layout/podpis.png"), new Point(0, height + 70));

    Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    bitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);      
}
```

As you can see the bitmap is saved and showed on aspx page after postback. What I wanna do is when user click Button1, then image is generated and browser download window pops up, without saving on server or showing on page. How to do this? Please help me.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [add a `Content-Disposition` header](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519).

Comment: So i should do something like this: 


 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileinfo.Name);     and     
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
   then    
 Response.WriteFile(fileinfo.FullName);    
   
How should I provide this dynamically generated image name and lenght?? I can't get this to work.

Comment: @Peter: The name can be anything you want; it doesn't matter. for example, you can do: `Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "abc.png");` The user will be prompted to download image "abc.png".

Answer (score 0):

After you save the file:

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=podpis.png" );
Response.WriteFile("yourfilepath/podpis.png");
Response.End;
```

Comment: Is that correct? I have my doubts because I'm not saving image as podpis.png. I just paste podpis.png to the bottom of dynamically created bitmap. How to pass that generated bitmap for user to download?

Comment: I believe instead of saving the file, you can write it DIRECTLY to the page... 

Response.WriteFile(Response.OutputStream);

Comment: The thing is I don't want to write it directly to the page. I want user to click button -> image is generating -> download windows pops up and user is saving image

Comment: The appendheader("content-disposition", "attachment;" should do it. Try it. I can't try it right now, but I am pretty sure that does the trick. The postback will be an attachment, and the browser will then decide what to do--download, save, etc.